# Print lines between two patterns in python

Tags: python, file-io

I have a file with the following structure:

```
@scaffold456
ATGTCGTGTCAGTG
GTACGTGTGTGG
+
!!!!!@!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!
@scaffold342
ATGGTGTCGTGGTG
ACGTGGC
+
!>!>!!!!+!!!!!
!!!!!!!
```

I would want an output like this:

```
>scaffold456
ATGTCGTGTCAGTG
GTACGTGTGTGG
>scaffold342
ATGGTGTCGTGGTG
ACGTGGC
```

I want to achieve this in Python, I started with the following:

```
fastq_filename = "test_file"
fastq = open(fastq_filename) # fastq is the file object

for line in fastq:
    if line.startswith("@"):
        print line.replace("@", ">")
```

but I can't go on anymore as I don't know:
1. How to print lines after a certain pattern match?
2. How I should specify that I want to skip lines between `+` till the next `@` sign?

This is a more complex topic in Python which I don't know, any help and explanation would be great, thanks!

Comment: Why not just use the [Biopython](http://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO) library to read these for you?

Comment: Because my file, although in fastq format, is not a raw read file, it's basically a fasta file that has been converted to fastq so there are many different number of lines belonging to each sequence, it looks messy. Plus, I am trying to learn python and it's a simple task to try to learn it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
fastq_filename = "test_file"
fastq = open(fastq_filename) # fastq is the file object    

canPrintLines = False # Boolean state variable to keep track of whether we want to be printing lines or not
for line in fastq:
    if line.startswith("@"):
        canPrintLines = True # We have found an @ so we can start printing lines
        line = line.replace("@", ">")
    elif line.startswith("+"):
        canPrintLines = False # We have found a + so we don't want to print anymore

    if canPrintLines:
        print(line)
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you please explain a bit on canPrintLines variable, apparently that's called a state variable?

Comment: @user1945881 it's a finite state machine, here with two states, so a simple boolean is enough to store the states, here are two states, printing and not printing

Comment: Yep, it's just keeping track of whether you last hit an @ or a +. If you last hit a + then you don't want to print any more lines until you hit another @ so we set the state to false. When we go to print the actual line, we check the state first and only print the line if the other conditions are met (i.e. the last "special" line started with an "@" not a "+")

Comment: Thanks! What I don't understand is that we set canPrintLines to False and it is True if the line starts with @, how come that the other lines are printed as well?

Comment: @KristyHughes: You _could_ put `line = line.replace("@", ">")` inside your first block, since we really don't need to call `replace` on every line we print, only on lines that begin with `@`.

Comment: @user1945881: The other lines are printed as well because once we set `canPrintLines` to `True` it _stays_ `True` until we set it to `False`, which only happens when we see a line that starts with `+`.

Comment: Great explanations. Is it correct if I say the 'type' of the variable canPrintLines is boolean?

Comment: @user1945881: Yes! Try this: `print(type(False))`

Comment: Good point @PM2Ring. It works how I had it before, but it was inefficient doing the replace on every printable line. Just updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how complex your lines with the `!` can get. I understand your question such that you wish to ignore all `+` and `@` signs inside these lines.

In that case I would introduce a state variable that stores whether we are currently working on an interesting line:

```
interesting_line=True
for line in fastq:
    if line.strip()=='+':   # Here we check for the + sign. You might need to adapt the test.
        interesting_line=False    # We don't care from now on
    if line.startswith('@'):
        interesting_line=True
    if interesting_line:
        # Do what you want with your line.
```

As I said, you might need to check if there can be situations where my simple tests don't match but this should give you a starting point

Answer (score 1):

This is an easy way to do it:

```
for line in fastq:
    if line and line[0].isalpha() or line[0]== '@':
        line = line.rstrip()
        print line.replace("@", ">")
```

Output:

```
>scaffold456
ATGTCGTGTCAGTG
GTACGTGTGTGG
>scaffold342
ATGGTGTCGTGGTG
ACGTGGC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for line in fastq:
    if line.startswith("@") or line.isalpha():
        print(line.replace("@", ">"))
```

Find the line that starts with `@` replace that with `>` and print it. 
Then find a line that contains only letters then print that line either.

Comment: I think, for further visitors it would be more helpful when you add some explainations for your intension.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will

1. ignore lines start with `+` or `!`
2. replace `@` with `>` if line start with `@`
3. write all other lines

> code

```
def format_file(path):
    new_lines = ""
    for line in open(path):
        if line.startswith("@"):
            new_lines += line.replace("@", ">")
        elif line.startswith("+"):
            pass
        elif line.startswith("!"):
            pass
        else:
            new_lines += line
    print new_lines

format_file("test_file")
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly then I think this is what you are looking for

```
for line in fastq:
    line = line.replace('\n','')
    n = len(line)
    mat = re.match(r'([ATGC]){%d}' % n,line)
    if mat:
        print line
    if line[0] == '@':
        print line.replace('@','>')
```

This uses [Regular Expressions](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm) which are incredibly useful. This says if it is either `A,T,G, or C` only in a line then print that line and then the other if statement is the same as what you have. `{%d}` matches `n` number of occurrences of the previous statement, `[ATGC]`. If there are more than `A,T,G, or C` then just add them between the square brackets.