# Print sections of a file from a matching line to an empty line

Tags: python

I want to print sections of a file from a matching line to an empty line, so I am looking for a way to express

```
sed '/^Word .*/,/^$/'
```

in Python.

For instance if |I had a file containing these sections:

```
Fruits
Apples:  10
Oranges: 20
Bananas:  5

Pastry
Cupcakes: 5
Buns:    10
Waffles: 20
```

How do I get the `Fruits` section?

In Perl I could do:

```
if ( /^Fruits/ .. /^$/ ) {
    print;
}
```

But I don't know how to do this in Python.

Comment: use a state machine... once you find the line you are looking for, use a boolean variable to indicate start of printing... then when you hit an empty line, set it to false.. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009882/how-to-read-large-file-line-by-line-in-python for reading file line by line

Comment: thanks, could you elaborate..? im very new to python :)

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11732383/python-read-specific-lines-of-text-between-two-strings and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31786823/print-lines-between-two-patterns-in-python

Comment: Ah, thanks! This helps :)

Comment: Does this have to be Python? It's easier in most other script languages.

Comment: Or, if your files aren't huge, you can read it whole and use either `split` or `search` with regex. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18568105/4653379) for example. There's no "flip-flop" operator in Python I think, but there are libraries implementing it -- or you can write a class/function to implement it, by using a flag while reading line by line.

Comment: Thanks zdim I'll check it out. Yes, Borodin, I too find this much easier in other scripting languages. I wanted to try this out in Python simply as a learning experiance :)

Comment: If it's for learning I would definitely suggest to write a function, or better yet a small class, that implements a sensible range (flip-flop) operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split the string by "\n\n" and look for string that start with Fruits

```
print(*(i for i in s.split("\n\n") if i.startswith("Fruits")))
```

Or if you have multiple groups:

```
print('\n\n'.join((i for i in s.split("\n\n") if i.startswith("Fruits"))))
```

Returns:

```
Fruits
Apples:  10
Oranges: 20
Bananas:  5
```

If:

```
s = """Fruits
Apples:  10
Oranges: 20
Bananas:  5

Pastry
Cupcakes: 5
Buns:    10
Waffles: 20"""
```

---

**furthermore**
You could also extract the items by a single line:

```
fruits = [i for i in s.split("\n\n") if i.startswith("Fruits")][0]
fruitdict = dict((i.strip() for i in i.split(":")) for i in fruits.split('\n')[1:])
fruitdict
```

Returns:

```
{'Apples': '10', 'Bananas': '5', 'Oranges': '20'}
```

---

**or** extract all categories:

```
categories = [i for i in s.split("\n\n")]

d = {}
for item in categories:
    rows = item.split('\n')
    d[rows[0]] = dict((i.strip() for i in i.split(":")) for i in rows[1:])
    # d[rows[0]] = dict((i.split(":")[0],int(i.split(":")[1])) for i in rows[1:])

d
```

Returns:

```
{'Fruits': {'Apples': '10', 'Bananas': '5', 'Oranges': '20'},
 'Pastry': {'Buns': '10', 'Cupcakes': '5', 'Waffles': '20'}}
```

Comment: Wow, nice answere! Thanks :)

Comment: @Dan-SimonMyrland No worries! If you found the answer useful consider marking it as accepted :). Good luck

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for [regex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

The following example extracts your sections using a regular expression:

```
import re

txt = """Fruits
Apples:  10
Oranges: 20
Bananas:  5

Pastry
Cupcakes: 5
Buns:    10
Waffles: 20"""

print re.findall("Fruits.*?(?:\n\n|$)", txt, re.DOTALL)
print
print re.findall("Pastry.*?(?:\n\n|$)", txt, re.DOTALL)
```

Here, `findall` will return a list with all occurrences of `"Word.*?(?:\n\n|$)"`in the string called `txt`. The regex used here means any sequence of characters which starts with `Word`, followed by any character `.` occurring 0 or more times in a [non-greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2301285/4041970) mode `*?`. Finally `(?:\n\n|$)` ensures the sequence ends with either a double newline `\n\n` or a end-of-string `$`. The option `re.DOTALL` ensures that  `.` includes newline.

Comment: Thanks @zdim for your constructive comment. Unfortunately `"\n\n"` was not enough to identify the end of any paragraph, because the last one is not followed by an empty line. One should look for a sequence ending with either of those character. The `(?:\n\n|$)` expression worked for me.

Comment: The `\n\n` is generally used to identify a paragraph -- except that it may not work for the very last one, as you noticed :)  Adding `$` is a good fix (and one can also add optional spaces there, `\s*$`, to effectively trim the possible trailing whitespace).